# Not showing delete function on ADO user story

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-boards

This delete function is not showing to a user. I have granted **Project Administrator** privilege. But still doesn't show that **Delete** button hence he cannot delete any user stories. This is all across ADO boards. I change the security permission from Project settings. But still the same issue exists. Really appreciate anyone can help me with this. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the work item, the user needs to have the Basic Access level.

You can navigate to **Organization Settings -> Users** to check if the user has **Stakeholder** Access level.

If yes, you can change the user Access level to **Basic**. Then the user will see the delete option in the Azure Boards.

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Remove, delete, or restore work items in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Oh... I totally forgot to check this as for the very first step. I assumed the user has the Basic access as he is the admin of that board. Thanks a lot Kevin. You remind me a good point.